# Using npm instagram-web-api on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, instagram

I was recently introduced to the npm instagram-web-api and decided to try using it to retrieve the pfp of users.

```js
const Instagram = require("instagram-web-api");
const insta = new Instagram({});
async function getpfp(userName){
    const user = await insta.getUserByUsername({ username: userName });
    return user.profile_pic_url;
}
```

This works just fine locally, however I recieve an error is when attempting to use it in an app hosted on Heroku.

```
(node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
     at /app/node_modules/instagram-web-api/lib/index.js:152:34
```

I still don't know all the ins and outs of Heroku so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Promise was rejected, since variable user or property of user is undefined. Either you forgot to setup environment variables on Heroku or this username does not exist. Are you sure you have your environment variables setup correctly?

Comment: I'm not using any environment variables for this. After looking into it a bit more, it seems the api isn't able to retrieve the user of the username that I give, though the username definitely exists. I tried using node-insta-web-api as well and run into a similar problem. Both of these worked locally but not on Heroku.